# C# - How can I declare a variable that will get populated by a database call inside an if statement?

Tags: c#, webmatrix

I want get data from a database call that's inside an if statement and then i want to be able to work with that data outside the if statement later in the page.

So, why doesn't this work?  And what can I do to make this work?  I just get the error message "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'selectedData' does not exist in the current context".  I tried to declare a "selectedData" variable outside of the if statement so it would be available, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that properly.

```
@{

    var testVariable = "blah";

    //set cache key and query based their being a craft name
    if(testVariable.Length > 0){

        var db = Database.Open("Connection"); 
        var selectedData = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Products");             
    } 

}


<div>
    @foreach (var row in selectedData){
        @row.ContentTitle <br />
        @row.ContentShortDescription <br />
    } 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a scope issue. You need to declare your variable outside of the if scope.

```
@{

    var testVariable = "blah";
    Type selectedData;

    //set cache key and query based their being a craft name
    if(testVariable.Length > 0){

        var db = Database.Open("Connection"); 
        selectedData = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Products");             
    } 

}


<div>
    @foreach (var row in selectedData){
        @row.ContentTitle <br />
        @row.ContentShortDescription <br />
    } 
</div>
```

I'm not familiar with the type here, so I used `Type`. Substitute the appropriate type there. Note that this snippet also doesn't make sure that selectedData is properly set before entering the loop. You should handle that as well.

Comment: I guess that is really where my problem lies.  I tried adding var selectedDate = ""; where you added the line, but then I get the following error "Compiler Error Message: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>' to 'string'".  So I guess I can't use "var" as the type, but what type would it be?

Comment: Well that's something I mentioned in the post.. Use the type returned by db.Query. I don't know what that is. Look at the documentation.

Comment: Try with `IEnumerable<dynamic> selectedData = null;`.

Comment: @GmG - thanks! that's exactly what I needed and I got it to work!  Thanks to everyone else as well for helping me understand!

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about scope.

Basicly, in C#, when you open a new set of `{}`, you declare a new scope. Variable create within that scope, are destroyed when exiting it. It is a fairly simplify explanation, not fully accurate, but it is an easy one to understand.

```
{
    var testVariable = "blah";

    //set cache key and query based their being a craft name
    if(testVariable.Length > 0)
    {

        var db = Database.Open("Connection"); 
        // Create a new variable.
        var selectedData = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Products");          
    } 
    // Variable doesn't exist anymore.
}
```

To fix it:

```
{
    var testVariable = "blah";
    // Create variable outside the if scope
    var selectedData = null; // Won't compile, compiler cannot find valid variable type.

    //set cache key and query based their being a craft name
    if(testVariable.Length > 0)
    {

        var db = Database.Open("Connection"); 
        // Assign a value to a variable
        selectedData = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Products");          
    } 
    // Variable still exist!
}
// Here, variable would cease to exist. :(
```

But here, the code won't compile, because the compile doesn't know what type `selectedData` is, because I assign it `null`  at its creation. So, let's say `selectedData` is of type `Data`:

```
{
    var testVariable = "blah";
    // Create variable outside the if scope
    Data selectedData = null; // Now it compiles. :)

    //set cache key and query based their being a craft name
    if(testVariable.Length > 0)
    {

        var db = Database.Open("Connection"); 
        // Assign a value to a variable
        selectedData = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Products");          
    } 
    // Variable still exist!
}
// Here, variable would cease to exist. :(
```

After that, you can do `if (selectedData != null)` to know if the data was correctly queried.

Comment: You should note that this won't actually compile as well.

Comment: @JordanKaye: Most likely. I still have a hard time to understand why people spam `var` all over the place. It just make tracking of variable type harder.

Comment: This will be the error CS0818 - "Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized"

Comment: @LightStriker I agree. I only use it in for loop variable declarations. But the reason is that `var anything = null` won't compile since `var` needs to be given a type when it's declared.

Comment: @sethflowers: Edited my answer to show why it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @LightStriker: I'm not able to put "Data selectedData = null;" like you have it.  I get the following error "Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Data' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @user1801249: What is the type of the stuff you query exactly? Do you know? If you put your cursor over the .Query method, the tooltip should tell you which type of variable to declare. From another comment from you, I would guess it should `IEnumerable<dynamic> selectedData = null;` ?